# scipy convolve and fftconvolve return different output

Tags: discrete-signals, python, convolution, autocorrelation, scipy

I'm writing an autocorrelation function using and I noticed a difference between fftconvolve and convolve that should use fft if it's faster.
This is my function with convolve:

```python
def autocorrelation(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    from scipy.signal import convolve
    return convolve(x, x[::-1])[len(x)-1:]
```

[image]

And that's with fftconvolve

```python
def autocorrelation(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
    return fftconvolve(x, x[::-1])[len(x)-1:]
```

[image]

The results are the same even if mode='fft' in convolve. Also note that the signal came from a wav file and this is the code I ran
[image]

Why do I get different outputs? Thanks :)

Comment: That's not at all the results I get, using `x = np.random.random(10) - 0.5`.  Are you sure you're giving it the same x vector in each case?  Is there some subtlety about the dimensions of the vector?

Comment: @TimWescott I'm 100% sure it's the same input, though for your random signal it's the same...

Comment: @TimWescott https://i.imgur.com/bobudSu.png

Comment: Could you _edit your question_ to either state that the samples come from a .wav file, or show the code?  While you're at it, show the shape of $x$ -- there's a good chance that reading a .wav file returns a $2 \times n$ or an $n \times 2$ matrix, and that the two flavors of convolution treat said matrices differently.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks, I edited the question with the hope it gives more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the `read` function from? What bit depth is the WAV file?  What dtype is `speech_signal`? Is the calculation overflowing?  If you convert to `float` dtype does it still happen?  Your first graph looks to be `int16`, limited to ±32768.

Comment: You're right! fftconvolve converts the type to float, I changed it to np.float64 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamKatav So it's `scipy.io.wavfile.read`?

Comment: Yes, it read it as int16